# Real analysis. Continuity of a product

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-continuity, boundary-value-problem

Let $X$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ two continuous bounded functions. Is the product $fg$ a uniformly continuous function? Prove or give a counterexample.

I would say it is false, since $x\sin(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous and it could be defined in $X$=[-1,1] and still not being uniformly continuous. But I couldn't prove it was not uniformly continuous, for if I take two sequences, $\pi n$ and $\pi n + \pi/ n$, they will not be defined in the domain.

On the other hand, if I take let's say $\sin(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$, using the same sequences I get that it's difference is $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. I know it's easy to prove  that if the function were uniformly continuous, well that would be all (supposing they are bounded). But that isn't the case. Nor we can assume $X$ is compact, or the like.
In summary I am stuck.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ uniformly continuous?  Or *just* bounded?

Comment: Sorry, I left out a hypotesis (but now the  statement is complete). They are bounded and continuos.

Comment: If that's the statement, it's false.  You can take $f$ to be any function that's bounded and continuous but not uniformly continuous, and $g$ to be a constant.

Comment: Oh well, thanks. In the meanwhile I came to an other counterexample, which is based on the same idea. $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin(x^2)}$ is bounded and two times $f$ is equal to $\sin(x^2)$ and this isn't uniformly continuos.